# cannot convert value of type '(QueryDocumentSnapshot).Type' to expected argument type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

*not sure what going wrong im new to firebase and the data isn't loading to my view controller*
**im just trying to get the data from my Firestore database and load it into my table view controller**

```
 import Foundation
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore


enum FcollectionReferece : String {

case User
case basket


case Category
case Items
case Verses
case MotivationDAILY
case teststuff


   }
   func FirebaseReferece(_ collectionReference1 : FcollectionReferece )->      CollectionReference {
//access a certain value
return Firestore.firestore().collection(collectionReference1.rawValue)
 }
```

//located in different view controller

```
func loadtoFIREBASE(){

    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error { print("we have a problem") }

        else {

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}

            var allData = snapshot.documents
            for restaurantDocuments in allData {

                allData.append(QueryDocumentSnapshot)
            }

        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The parameter of `append` must be an instance, not a type. But the code makes no sense for several reasons.

Comment: What type is `allData` and what is it supposed to do? Is it the table's data source property? Have you populated table view's before?

Comment: Your code defines allData as an array of documents `var allData = snapshot.documents` but then it's trying to append a different class of data onto the array `allData.append(QueryDocumentSnapshot)` so that won't work and appending a class type onto an array in this use case doesn't make any sense. Even if you try to append the snapshot itself `allData.append(snapshot)` won't make sense since the snapshot contains other documents. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```swift
allData.append(QueryDocumentSnapshot)
```

to:

```swift
allData.append(snapshot)
```

Comment: That won't work as allData is already defined as an array of QueryDocumentSnapshot objects `var allData = snapshot.documents` and can't be redefined as a FIRQuerySnapshot